# Issue with Creating records thru flow with all access data in community portal

Tags: community, custom-object, security, create-records, guest-user

Current Config

1. Organization-wide setting -
   Sharing Setting
   Custom Object **LeadStage** -
   External sharing -  Public Read /Write
2. Community Portal Guest User Profile
   Custom Object **LeadStage** - Create, Edit

Requirement - Create a record in this object and give users options to create, retrieve within 15 days, and update the records also.

**I am using a **flow with all data access** and trying to create a record in a custom object**  but the system is not creating a record and no error message also in production.

Can anyone please help with such an issue?